# How to convert Bitmap into Base64 String without compressing?

Tags: android, base64, android-bitmap

I am trying to convert a bitmap image into Base64 String using this code. I am getting a very low-quality image. How can I get a good quality image after convert bitmap into a Base64 Sring?

```
public String BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    base64Image = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return base64Image;
}
```

If I have a 5MB image, after conversion, I am getting only 160KB image. But in my case, I don't want to compress my image too much I just want to get Base64 String based on Bitmap image only JPEG format, not any other.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 public String getBase64Image(Bitmap bitmap) {
            try {
                ByteBuffer buffer = 
                ByteBuffer.allocate(bitmap.getRowBytes() * 
                bitmap.getHeight());
                bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
                byte[] data = buffer.array();
                return Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: It will work definitely, but in my case, if select PNG image this code will not convert into JPEG format. If you have any other solution please suggest me

Comment: then first convert any type of image to JPEG and apply this. Flllow this for Image conversion: https://www.codejava.net/java-se/graphics/convert-image-formats