# How to get the correct base64 encoded string from a bitmap in java (Android)?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I'm working on eye detection project and I use for that the Tensorflow library and MLKit firebase API for the custom model
I have tested the model on Android on the same image that I have tested from the frozen inference model.
But I have got false predictions with the tflite model comparing to the results that I have got from the frozen model

I'm trying to get the predictions from the Imageview.
This is the pre-processing that I used:
Imageview -> bitmap -> createscaledbitmap() -> getpredictionsfrombitmap()

Actually, I doubt that the problem is in pre-processing ( image input ).

I get an answer that the problem maybe is from the input image.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31722

I have tried to print the encoded base64 String on java and on python and compare those results.
unfortunately, I have got different results.

The results in python are the same that I have got from a website that does the conversion

I have tested more than 30 functions posted on the StackOverflow as answers but all of them doesn't work for me, for e.g this solution below:

[#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55785798/how-to-convert-bitmap-into-base64-string-without-compressing)

I would like to find a correct function that convert the input bitmap to encoded base64 String with java ( Android )

I have posted a similar question [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57623370/why-i-got-different-result-when-i-encode-the-same-image-to-base64-string-java) but I didn't get any answer for it.
I really need help to solve problem.
Thanks